# Java Unit Tests giving NullPointer Exception

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

i have a unit test throwing NullPointer Exception
when i put the test in another file, its running fine
below is the piece of code. other tests in the same file are running without any errors.

```
@Test
public void validateShouldFailIfThereExistsABillingCycleWithSameId() {
    final String expectedErrorMessage = "Billing Cycle with id  " + id + " already exists";

    when(billingCycleServiceAuditable.
            findBillingCycleById(id, locale, DefaultAuth.SYSTEM_USER_NAME.getValue())).
            thenReturn(Optional.of(billingCycle));

    when(messageService.getMessage(I18Code.MESSAGE_CHARGING_BILLING_CYCLE_EXISTS.getCode(),
            new String[]{id.toString()}, locale)).thenReturn(expectedErrorMessage);
    when(mapper.map(billingCycle)).thenReturn(billingCycleDto);
    when(mapper.map(billingCycleDto)).thenReturn(billingCycle);

    final CommonResponse response = billingCycleValidator.validate(billingCycle, userAction, locale, DefaultAuth.SYSTEM_USER_NAME.getValue());
    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEq    @Test
public void validateShouldFailIfThereExistsABillingCycleWithSameId() {
    final String expectedErrorMessage = "Billing Cycle with id  " + id + " already exists";

    when(billingCycleServiceAuditable.
            findBillingCycleById(id, locale, DefaultAuth.SYSTEM_USER_NAME.getValue())).
            thenReturn(Optional.of(billingCycle));

    when(messageService.getMessage(I18Code.MESSAGE_CHARGING_BILLING_CYCLE_EXISTS.getCode(),
            new String[]{id.toString()}, locale)).thenReturn(expectedErrorMessage);
    when(mapper.map(billingCycle)).thenReturn(billingCycleDto);
    when(mapper.map(billingCycleDto)).thenReturn(billingCycle);

    final CommonResponse response = billingCycleValidator.validate(billingCycle, userAction, locale, DefaultAuth.SYSTEM_USER_NAME.getValue());
    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEquals(expectedErrorMessage, response.getNarrative());

    verify(billingCycleServiceAuditable,
            times(1))
            .findBillingCycleById(anyLong(), any(Locale.class), anyString());
}uals(expectedErrorMessage, response.getNarrative());

    verify(billingCycleServiceAuditable,
            times(1))
            .findBillingCycleById(anyLong(), any(Locale.class), anyString());
}
```

Comment: include the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your test class make sure the class is annotated with `testrunner` as bellow

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BillingCycleValidatorImplCreateBillingCycleActionTest {
}
```